# Do you pay a part time nanny for vacation?

Tags: money, babysitting

We have a part-time nanny 3 days a week and we generally pay her cash for those 12 days a month. Our family is going on vacation for 2 weeks where her services won't be necessary and we're wondering if we're still expected to pay her for those 2 weeks?

Comment: Never underestimate the value of a good nanny. If all it takes to keep them happy and available to you is a few extra bucks then I would do it.

Comment: Do you want to still have a nanny when you come back from your holiday? If you don't pay her, she will think it absolutely appropriate to find another family.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are away quite a lot, but pay our nanny when we are away anyhow. She is dependent on this income and doing otherwise would feel weird. Since we are away way more that the 4 weeks of vacation there are per year here, we sometimes make deals with her to stay an hour longer the week after and things like that.

Answer (score 7):

It depends:

- Most important, what did you agree to?
- Is there an expectation of vacation pay?
- What are your neighbours/friends doing?
- What are your country's laws?
- How much do you like your nanny?
- Is there a reason why you might want
  to continue paying during a vacation
  so that they won't look for another
  employer?

I know of some people who pay their nannies 1/2 wage during vacations and others who bring their nannies with them on vacations. I also know of people getting full pay during vacations but this is usually for full-time work.

In the end, you have to go with what you feel is right. You need to depend on your nanny and maintain a good relationship. Chances are that they are worth every penny and more.

I recommend scrimping somewhere else and talking it over with them.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that it would be a very good thing to continue paying, as in managing your relationship with her.  Personally, if she were a very good nanny, I would pay for the time, and let her know you are doing it for her good services.  In the end, it will not amount to a great deal of money and I am sure the benefits in your relationship would be worth it.

I don't think it's black and white as this person is responsible for looking after your loved ones and that relationship has to be a good one.

However, in the strict defintion of part time laws in this country, if you do nto have a contract of employment with thsi person, you have no obligations to pay her.  However, as I said, just remember what she's employed to do.

Answer (score -2):

Since the question mentions paying cash, to me it sounds like under the table work (i.e. not paying taxes, and disregarding other rules). If that is the case then I would say that you make your own rules. Did your original agreement say anything about vacation pay? If not, then none is included.

So I  don't see why you should pay for services that are not performed, unless it's purely to keep good relations with the nanny, or because there is a legal work agreement that demands it.

Comment: Most countries laws do not allow for not paying vacation for employees, so it depends on if she is an employee or not. Some countries (like Sweden) says the nanny has to be an employee as long as you are her only employer. Of course, if you don't have a contract and don't pay taxes, things are different, but then you may be in the shit because you are breaking the law. :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer.